# Angular2: Custom validation for fields with numbers only

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, validation, angular, angular2-forms

Im trying to do custom validation in angular 2, I have included what needed in my knowledge but Im unable to validate

```
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES, AbstractControl, ControlGroup
,FormBuilder,Control, Validators } from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
selector : 'cusValidate',
template: `
 <form [ngFormModel] = "myform" (ngSubmit) = "onSubmit()">
 <lable>Credit Card Number</lable>
 <div>
 <input type = "text" [ngFormControl] = "inputfield"/>
 <div [class.has-error] = '!inval'>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
`,
directives : [FORM_DIRECTIVES]

})
export class cusValidation{
myform : ControlGroup;
inputfield : AbstractControl;

constructor(fb : FormBuilder){
   this.myform = fb.group({
        'inputfield' : ['' , Validators.compose([Validators.required
,this.formValidator])]
    })
   this.inputfield = this.myform.controls['inputfield']
}

 formValidator(val : Control) :any {
     if(val.value.match(/^123/)){
         return {inval : true};
     }
 }

onSubmit(){
    console.log('submit function called')
}
}
bootstrap(cusValidation);
```

also validator function was in other file that i included but here its in class and im accessing using this.function, also how to apply appropriate twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce it in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/As15rN9GfgkoprVQ1rOq?p=preview) and validation is called fine.

I'm not sure what you expect. Currently the `formValidator` indicates an error when `123` is entered, everything else is considered valid ('ab', '12', 'xyz123').

If you want to indicate an error return an object with error key and an arbitrary value (for example error message).

If you want to indicate **no error** (value is valid) then return `null`.

```
formValidator(val : Control) :any {
     if(val.value.match(/.*[^0-9].*/)){
         return {inval : true};
     }
 }
```

Updated [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/As15rN9GfgkoprVQ1rOq?p=preview)

Comment: I want as soon as user dont follow to enter only number the input field changes its color to indicate error and show msg "numbers are allowed only"

Comment: Is it not enough to return, return {inval : true}; from inside function

Comment: Sure it's enough. I just suspect currently it's not returned for the situations you intended it to but you didn't provide enough information for me to know what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: So how can i do this

Comment: I don't know yet what "this" should be. What do you want?

Comment: Sorry, my solutions had some flaws. I updated my answer and added a new Plunker link that shows 3 different ways to access the "valid" state of the form (1x) and the control (2x).

Answer (score 4):

You are using Angular2,
then you can use html5 form fields. Why do not you use the  '`<input type ="number"/>`?

Comment: still it will allow `e`(exponential) character on that input field.. which would again doesn't make sense.